# NullPointerException at java.awt.EventQueue.getCurrentEventImpl

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, java-8

I've migrated a Swing application to Java 8 and recently we see the following NPE exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.EventQueue.getCurrentEventImpl(EventQueue.java:848)
at java.awt.EventQueue.getCurrentEvent(EventQueue.java:842)
at java.awt.Component.requestFocusHelper(Component.java:7628)
at java.awt.Component.requestFocusHelper(Component.java:7620)
at java.awt.Component.requestFocus(Component.java:7495)
at javax.swing.JComponent.requestFocus(JComponent.java:1504)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPopupMenuUI$MenuKeyboardHelper.stateChanged(BasicPopupMenuUI.java:1173)
at javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.fireStateChanged(MenuSelectionManager.java:202)
at javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.setSelectedPath(MenuSelectionManager.java:129)
at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.setVisible(JPopupMenu.java:784)
at javax.swing.JPopupMenu.show(JPopupMenu.java:965)
at org.tbee.swing.StandardComponentPopupMenu.showJTableMenu(StandardComponentPopupMenu.java:555)
at org.tbee.swing.StandardComponentPopupMenu$2.run(StandardComponentPopupMenu.java:175)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Migrating back to J7 is a problem, because lambda's are being used, so I cannot easily confirm that this really is a J8 issue. But the code in question has been running for several years now, surviving Java 5, 6 and 7. So chances are it is J8 specific.

The reason for the exception is that currentEvent in EventQueue is not set. This is done by its setCurrentEventAndMostRecentTimeImpl(AWTEvent e). However, if I trace back in the stack, I see that in EventQueue:756 (Java 1.8.0u45) the dispatch is done after exactly that method is called.

```
    if (event instanceof ActiveEvent) {
        // This could become the sole method of dispatching in time.
        setCurrentEventAndMostRecentTimeImpl(event);
        ((ActiveEvent)event).dispatch();
```

I'm in the dark why that variable is null. Debugging is close to impossible, because of all the events being handled by that piece of code.

Is anyone aware of changes in Swing's event handling in J8?

Comment: I have confirmed it is J8, because I had a test class for the StandardComponentPopupMenu you see in the stack. It runs correctly on J6 and J7, but fails with the NPE on J8.

Comment: Is there someone [pushing a new `EventQueue` instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#push-java.awt.EventQueue-)?

Comment: I am still seeing this sporadically in JDK 11.0.4: our application code calls `EventQueue.getCurrentEvent()` and gets a null return, despite the fact that in the call-stack I can see that `Component.dispatchEventImpl` (`JEditorPane`) has recently gone past the point which should have set a non-null value into `EventQueue.currentEvent` (held by `WeakReference`). Is it valid for the WeakReference to be released while code in the call-stack still holds a local-variable reference to the event??

Comment: After the patch below it never came back. I'm running it on J15 now.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yeah, I often find `invokeLater` is a good idea in that kind of context. (Avoid starting a new action in the middle of processing other events - you can suffer from inconsistent / partially-modified internal state.) Unfortunately the crash I encountered is a different use-case - the code needs an immediate answer to "is this sill processing the same event?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, the opening of the popup menu had to be rescheduled on the EDT, even though the code opening it is running on the EDT.

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jpopupMenu.show(c, x, y);
        }
    });
```

Only when running on J8.

Comment: Since you are using Java 8, you can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> jpopupMenu.show(c, x, y) );`

Comment: Yes, well, the Swing library where this code is from (being used in a J8 application) is stil based on J6.

Answer (score 2):

Also, ensure that if you are installing an alternate event queue that you are doing it on it's own event, like:

```
Swingutilities.invokeLater(){
    ... run() {
       ..do event queue push();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the event queue push is not migrating the current event, only pending events.

Comment: Do you have a source for this statement?

Answer (score -2):

Below works fine :

```
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().push(Customized Event);
                  }
              });
```